Durable Function with Global Exception Handler
We have a Durable Function with multiple orchestrators and activities. We would like to use a middleware as global exception handler instead of handling it in every orchestrator/activity. We can catch the error in the middleware but in the Durable Function Monitor the instance is green. We would like to get it red and send the error text to the monitor. Is there any way to achieve this?
Edit: Added code
internal sealed class ErrorHandlerMiddleware(ILogger<ErrorHandlerMiddleware> logger) : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware {

    private readonly ILogger<ErrorHandlerMiddleware> _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            // How to call DurableOrchestrationContextBase.SetCustomStatus from here?
        }
    }
}


Can you provide the code that you have used?

@RithwikBojja done

I have used below code to use a middleware as global exception handler to handle the exceptions.
GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware(ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
         // Executes the orchestration function
            await next(context); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred.");
         // you can re-throw the exception to handle it elsewhere(or)mark it as failed.
            throw;  
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
var builder = FunctionsApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication();

// Register exception handler middleware.
builder.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware>(); 
 
builder.Build().Run();

Function.cs:
 public static class Function1
 {
     [Function(nameof(Function1))]
     public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
                [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
     {
         var logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
         var outputs = new List<string>();

         try
         {
             outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
             context.SetCustomStatus("Tokyo");
             throw new Exception("Something went wrong in the orchestration.");

             outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
             context.SetCustomStatus("Seattle");
             outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));
             context.SetCustomStatus("London");

             return outputs;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             logger.LogError($"Orchestrator failed: {ex.Message}");
             context.SetCustomStatus($"Error: {ex.Message}");
             // Rethrow the orchestration to mark it as failed
             throw new Exception("Orchestrator execution failed.", ex);
         }
     }

     [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
     public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
     {
         var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
         logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
         return $"Hello {name}!";
     }

     [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
     public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
     {
         var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");
         string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Function1));

         logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
         return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
     }

Output:
Functions:

        Function1_HttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7182/api/Function1_HttpStart

        Function1: orchestrationTrigger

        SayHello: activityTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-02T09:52:41.939Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-12-02T09:52:43.675Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1_HttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=e618a276-60b9-4feb-84ce-3db17390ca3c)
[2024-12-02T09:52:59.923Z] Scheduling new Function1 orchestration with instance ID '0958069fc24c4678b7486bf01fc6b995' and 0 bytes of input data.
[2024-12-02T09:53:00.275Z] Started orchestration with ID = '0958069fc24c4678b7486bf01fc6b995'.
[2024-12-02T09:53:00.398Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1_HttpStart' (Succeeded, Id=e618a276-60b9-4feb-84ce-3db17390ca3c, Duration=16761ms)
[2024-12-02T09:53:00.438Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=34b6427d-ccfa-4c8b-8b0e-49dd33e86521)
[2024-12-02T09:53:06.458Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=34b6427d-ccfa-4c8b-8b0e-49dd33e86521, Duration=6070ms)
[2024-12-02T09:53:06.551Z] Executing 'Functions.SayHello' (Reason='(null)', Id=2f65ef8f-bba4-4eca-9c9c-f5c3884c462a)
[2024-12-02T09:53:08.907Z] Saying hello to Tokyo.
[2024-12-02T09:53:08.913Z] Executed 'Functions.SayHello' (Succeeded, Id=2f65ef8f-bba4-4eca-9c9c-f5c3884c462a, Duration=2369ms)
[2024-12-02T09:53:08.985Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=4a739a12-8f60-4b48-b24d-1699a98254b4)

[2024-12-02T09:53:10.430Z] Orchestrator failed: Something went wrong in the orchestration.
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.704Z] An unhandled exception occurred.
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.708Z] Result: An unhandled exception occurred.
Exception: System.Exception: Orchestrator execution failed.
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.712Z]  ---> System.Exception: Something went wrong in the orchestration.
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.715Z]    at FunctionApp11.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp11\Function1.cs:line 25
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.719Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.723Z]    at FunctionApp11.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp11\Function1.cs:line 42
//Removed few logs
[2024-12-02T09:53:10.939Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 306. IsReplay: False. State: Failed. RuntimeStatus: Failed. HubName: TestHubName. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.13.7. SequenceNum er: 8. TaskEventId: -1

Application Insights of the function app:

